# what is the Aws cloudwatch events equivalent in gcp

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events

How we can Monitor Resource Changes In Google Cloud and how to monitor for GCP resource changes, automate alerts based on those changes and invoke an action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a complete Operation Suite(formerly known as Stackdriver) on Google Cloud Platform that provides the features mentioned above.
Official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/products/operations

Cloud Monitoring, Cloud Alerting can be used to alerts based on different events. Alerts can be published to different channels like email, slack, etc.